# Functions that are sets of all function - proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm going through the book Proofs and fundamentals, by Bloch, and it doesn't include a solution manual for it's examples. It doesn't have many examples on notation and proof strategy for certain cases, so I needed a little help.

[image]

Although I understand the idea, and can draw it out, I'm not sure how to write it in decent proof notation. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: apologies, my idea is this: theres some function in $F(C,A\times B)$ such that theres some $x$ within $C$ that means $g(x)$ is within $A\times B$. Similarly, the second two imply that for some function within $F(A,C)$ there exists a value $x$ such that $g(x)=C$. and similarly for the third part from $B\rightarrow C$. It's easy to see with drawing it out that these two are the same because one will have a part within A and the other will lead to a part within $B$, so their cross will be the same. I wanted to go about proving it by setting a function $f$ within $F(C,AxB)$ and then working from there, but I really have no idea where to start or the notation.

Comment: If your only problem is formalization, you should at least write your intuitive idea of the proof so that we can help you

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! I added a small edited section now with my ideas - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\Phi:\mathcal{F}(C,A\times B)\rightarrow\mathcal{F}(C,A)\times\mathcal{F}(C,B)$ by $\Phi(f)=(\pi_A\circ f,\pi_B\circ f)$ where $\pi_A:A\times B\rightarrow A$ and $\pi_B:A\times B\rightarrow B$ are the projection maps.

To see that $\Phi$ is injective, suppose $\Phi(f)=\Phi(g)$ so $(\pi_A\circ f,\pi_B\circ f)=(\pi_A\circ g,\pi_B\circ g)$. Then $f(c)=\Bigl(\pi_A\bigl(f(c)\bigr),\pi_B\bigl(f(c)\bigr)\Bigr)=\Bigl(\pi_A\bigl(g(c)\bigr),\pi_B\bigl(g(c)\bigr)\Bigr)=g(c)$ whenever $c\in C$. Hence $f=g$ and $\Phi$ is injective.

To see that $\Phi$ is surjective, let $(g,h)\in \mathcal{F}(C,A)\times\mathcal{F}(C,B)$. Let $f\in\mathcal{F}(C,A\times B)$ be given by $f(c)=(g(c),h(c))$. Then $\Phi(f)=(g,h)$ and $\Phi$ is surjective.

Proving the second exercise is similar.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really clarified the notation for me and I believe I can get both problems done now.